# Click password option only if argument equals something

Tags: python, python-click

In click, I'm defining this command:

```
@click.command('time', short_help='Timesheet Generator')
@click.argument('time_command', type=click.Choice(['this', 'last']))
@click.argument('data_mode', type=click.Choice(['excel', 'exchange']), default='exchange')
@click.option('--password', prompt=True, hide_input=True, confirmation_prompt=False)
@pass_context
def cli(ctx, time_command, data_mode, password):
```

The issue I have is that I only want the password to prompt if the `data_mode` argument equals `exchange`.  How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 2):

We can remove the need for a prompt if another parameter does not match a specific value by building a custom class derived from `click.Option`, and in that class over riding the `click.Option.handle_parse_result()` method like:

#### Custom Class:

```
import click

def PromptIf(arg_name, arg_value):

    class Cls(click.Option):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['prompt'] = kwargs.get('prompt', True)
            super(Cls, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
            assert any(c.name == arg_name for c in ctx.command.params), \
                "Param '{}' not found for option '{}'".format(
                    arg_name, self.name)

            if arg_name not in opts:
                raise click.UsageError(
                    "Illegal usage: `%s` is a required parameter with" % (
                        arg_name))

            # remove prompt from 
            if opts[arg_name] != arg_value:
                self.prompt = None

            return super(Cls, self).handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)

    return Cls
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to `click.option` decorator like:

```
@click.option('--an_option', cls=PromptIf('an_argument', 'an_arg_value'))
```

pass in the name of the parameter to examine for the desired value, and the value to check for.

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.option()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be overridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Option.handle_parse_result()` and disable the need to prompt if the other specified parameter does not match the desired.

Note: This answer was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349292/7311767).

#### Test Code:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('an_argument', type=click.Choice(['excel', 'exchange']),
                default='exchange')
@click.option('--password', hide_input=True, confirmation_prompt=False,
              cls=PromptIf('an_argument', 'exchange'))
def cli(an_argument, password):
    click.echo(an_argument)
    click.echo(password)

cli('exchange'.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting this up to multiple commands.
For example, `time` would be the entry point command. Either `time_excel` or `time_exchange` would then be invoked by `time` based on the value of `data_mode`. One could have a password prompt while the other wouldn't.

See [Invoking Other Commands](http://click.pocoo.org/5/advanced/#invoking-other-commands) in Click's documentation.