# Click Command Line Interfaces: Make options required if other optional option is unset

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

When writing a command-line interface (CLI) with the Python [click library](http://click.pocoo.org/6/), is it possible to define e.g. three options where the second and third one are only required if the first (optional) one was left unset?

My use case is a log-in system which allows me to authenticate either via an `authentication token` (option 1), or, alternatively, via `username` (option 2) and `password` (option 3).

If the token was given, there is no need to check for `username` and `password` being defined or prompting them. Otherwise, if the token was omitted then `username` and `password` become required and must be given.

Can this be done somehow using callbacks?

My code to get started which of course does not reflect the intended pattern:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--authentication-token', prompt=True, required=True)
@click.option('--username', prompt=True, required=True)
@click.option('--password', hide_input=True, prompt=True, required=True)
def login(authentication_token, username, password):
    print(authentication_token, username, password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login()
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This can be done by building a custom class derived from `click.Option`, and in that class over riding the `click.Option.handle_parse_result()` method like:

#### Custom Class:

```
import click

class NotRequiredIf(click.Option):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.not_required_if = kwargs.pop('not_required_if')
        assert self.not_required_if, "'not_required_if' parameter required"
        kwargs['help'] = (kwargs.get('help', '') +
            ' NOTE: This argument is mutually exclusive with %s' %
            self.not_required_if
        ).strip()
        super(NotRequiredIf, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
        we_are_present = self.name in opts
        other_present = self.not_required_if in opts

        if other_present:
            if we_are_present:
                raise click.UsageError(
                    "Illegal usage: `%s` is mutually exclusive with `%s`" % (
                        self.name, self.not_required_if))
            else:
                self.prompt = None

        return super(NotRequiredIf, self).handle_parse_result(
            ctx, opts, args)
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to `click.option` decorator like:

```
@click.option('--username', prompt=True, cls=NotRequiredIf,
              not_required_if='authentication_token')
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.option()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be overridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Option.handle_parse_result()` and disable the need to `user/password` if `authentication-token` token is present, and complain if both `user/password` are `authentication-token` are present.

Note: This answer was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491504/7311767)

#### Test Code:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--authentication-token')
@click.option('--username', prompt=True, cls=NotRequiredIf,
              not_required_if='authentication_token')
@click.option('--password', prompt=True, hide_input=True, cls=NotRequiredIf,
              not_required_if='authentication_token')
def login(authentication_token, username, password):
    click.echo('t:%s  u:%s  p:%s' % (
        authentication_token, username, password))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login('--username name --password pword'.split())
    login('--help'.split())
    login(''.split())
    login('--username name'.split())
    login('--authentication-token token'.split())
```

#### Results:

from `login('--username name --password pword'.split())`:

```
t:None  u:name  p:pword
```

from `login('--help'.split())`:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --authentication-token TEXT
  --username TEXT              NOTE: This argument is mutually exclusive with
                               authentication_token
  --password TEXT              NOTE: This argument is mutually exclusive with
                               authentication_token
  --help                       Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 18):

Slightly improved [Stephen Rauch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349292/7311767) to have multiple mutex parameters.

```
import click

class Mutex(click.Option):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.not_required_if:list = kwargs.pop("not_required_if")

        assert self.not_required_if, "'not_required_if' parameter required"
        kwargs["help"] = (kwargs.get("help", "") + "Option is mutually exclusive with " + ", ".join(self.not_required_if) + ".").strip()
        super(Mutex, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
        current_opt:bool = self.name in opts
        for mutex_opt in self.not_required_if:
            if mutex_opt in opts:
                if current_opt:
                    raise click.UsageError("Illegal usage: '" + str(self.name) + "' is mutually exclusive with " + str(mutex_opt) + ".")
                else:
                    self.prompt = None
        return super(Mutex, self).handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
```

use like this:

```
@click.group()
@click.option("--username", prompt=True, cls=Mutex, not_required_if=["token"])
@click.option("--password", prompt=True, hide_input=True, cls=Mutex, not_required_if=["token"])
@click.option("--token", cls=Mutex, not_required_if=["username","password"])
def login(ctx=None, username:str=None, password:str=None, token:str=None) -> None:
    print("...do what you like with the params you got...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant, in which has not_required_if must be specified with the snake_case variant, required is used rather than prompt, and importantly, it works if the other arguments are passed through environment variables rather than on the command line by using ctx.command.get_params(...) and param.consume_value(...):

```py
import click


class Mutex(click.Option):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.not_required_if: list = kwargs.pop("not_required_if")

        assert self.not_required_if, "'not_required_if' parameter required"
        kwargs["help"] = (kwargs.get("help", "") + "Option is mutually exclusive with " + ", ".join(self.not_required_if) + ".").strip()
        super(Mutex, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
        current_opt: bool = self.consume_value(ctx, opts)
        for other_param in ctx.command.get_params(ctx):
            if other_param is self:
                continue
            if other_param.human_readable_name in self.not_required_if:
                other_opt: bool = other_param.consume_value(ctx, opts)
                if other_opt:
                    if current_opt:
                        raise click.UsageError(
                            "Illegal usage: '" + str(self.name)
                            + "' is mutually exclusive with "
                            + str(other_param.human_readable_name) + "."
                        )
                    else:
                        self.required = None
        return super(Mutex, self).handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
```