# argparse mutual exclusion between one or two arguments

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Here's the minimal code for what I want to do,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( prog="test")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='sub-commands')
num  = subparsers.add_parser("num")
num.add_argument("-n")
numr = num.add_argument_group("Required arguments")

onr  =numr.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
onr.add_argument("-x")
onr2 = onr.add_argument_group("new")
onr2.add_argument("-y")
onr2.add_argument("-z")
```

So what I want is that, the user must provide either `x` or both `y`,`z`, so thought of adding a mutually exclusive group of one argument and one group. And this must be under the sub command `num`. This code gives this output

```
usage: test num [-h] [-n N] -x X [-y Y] [-z Z]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -n N

Required arguments:
  -x X
```

No info about `y`,`z` , also giving both `y`,`z` doesn't work

```
python test.py num -y 9 -z 10
usage: test num [-h] [-n N] -x X [-y Y] [-z Z]
test num: error: one of the arguments -x is required
```

How do I achieve this using argparse, or is it even possible?

Comment: How about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247099/click-command-line-interfaces-make-options-required-if-other-optional-option-is/44349292#44349292 ?

Comment: `argument_group` is only used for group arguments in the `help`, as you do with `numr`.  It ok to put `onr` in `numr` for labeling purpose.  `onr2` doesn't do anything for you.  You need to do your own testing for '-x', '-y', '-z'.  There isn't a mechanism that does a `x xor (y and z)`.

Comment: What should the usage look like?  `usage: test num [-h] [-n N] (-x X | ([-y Y] ??? [-z Z]))`.   `argparse` uses the vertical bar to mark the mutually exclusive `xor` test, `(x | y | z)`.  But what would convey a 'both' or a 'any' relation?  I have explored generalizing the `xor` test, but generalizing the `usage` display was too messy.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Then I will try to post process the arguments with a `xor` after getting the arguments from argparse.

Comment: I expected it to look like this  `usage: test num [-h] [-n N] (-x X | (-y Y -z Z))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend removing the fancy testing on x,y,z, and doing it yourself after parsing.  The logic of trying to do this in `argparse` itself is too complex.  Testing isn't too bad, but a good user interface is harder.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( prog="test")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='sub-commands')
num  = subparsers.add_parser("num")
num.add_argument("-n")
numr = num.add_argument_group("Required arguments")

#onr  =numr.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
numr.add_argument("-x")
#onr2 = onr.add_argument_group("new")
numr.add_argument("-y")
numr.add_argument("-z")

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if args.x is None:
    if args.y is None or args.z is None:
        parser.error('both y and z are required')
```

sample session:

```
1122:~/mypy$ python3 stack54033455.py -h
usage: test [-h] {num} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

sub-commands:
  {num}
2212:~/mypy$ python3 stack54033455.py num -h
usage: test num [-h] [-n N] [-x X] [-y Y] [-z Z]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -n N

Required arguments:
  -x X
  -y Y
  -z Z
2212:~/mypy$ python3 stack54033455.py num -x foo
Namespace(n=None, x='foo', y=None, z=None)
2212:~/mypy$ python3 stack54033455.py num -y foo
Namespace(n=None, x=None, y='foo', z=None)
usage: test [-h] {num} ...
test: error: both y and z are required
2212:~/mypy$ python3 stack54033455.py num -y foo -z bar
Namespace(n=None, x=None, y='foo', z='bar')
```

I explored allowing nested groups with generalized logic in https://bugs.python.org/issue11588 (Add "necessarily inclusive" groups to argparse).  My current thinking is that it would be nice to give you access to the `seen_actions` set, so you can do testing for usage without depending on the `is None` test.  The current usage formatter is too brittle to generalize.

Using:

```
num  = subparsers.add_parser("num", usage="test num [-h] [-n N] (-x X | (-y Y -z Z))")
```

works.

Comment: It would have been perfect if I just could add `usage="test num [-h] [-n N] (-x X | (-y Y -z Z))"` in the subparser

Comment: `add_parser` accepts a `usage` parameter (and most of the parameters that `ArgumentParser` takes).