# How to show/hide input option based on the first input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm writing a command-line tool using Python [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) package.

For the user input, I want to show/hide the next input option based on the first input.

Here is the sample code:

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--user/--no-user', prompt='do you want to add user?')
@click.option('--new-user', prompt='add user')
def add_user(user, new_user):
    print(user)
    print(new_user)


add_user()
```

I want to show 2nd prompt(`'--new-user'`) only if the user type yes for the first input(`'--user/--no-user'`).

Any help how can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247099/click-command-line-interfaces-make-options-required-if-other-optional-option-is

Comment: If you have a new question then you must create a new post as indicated by the SO rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use a custom callback:

```
import click

def prompt_user(ctx, param, user):
    new_user = None
    if user:
        new_user = click.prompt('username')
    return (user, new_user)


@click.command()
@click.option('--user/--no-user', prompt='do you want to add user?', callback=prompt_user)
def add_user(user):
    user, new_user = user
    print(user)
    print(new_user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_user()

$ python3.8 user.py
do you want to add user? [y/N]: y
username: no
True
no
$ python3.8 user.py
do you want to add user? [y/N]: N
False
None
```

Note that `prompt_user` returns a tuple of two values. So the line `user, new_user = user` sets `user` equal to the first value and `new_user` to the second. See [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) for more explanation.

Comment: thankyou very much for your answer. One thing I could not understand is `user, new_user = user`. This means that `user, new_user` should have the same value, but they should not because they have different values (in case of yes, user=True and new_user = no). Can you please say a few words about this?

Comment: @Yahya Added an explanation - it's due to tuple unpacking.

Comment: `user, new_user = user` here `user` on the right side is basically calling the `prompt_user` that returns two values. am I right?

Comment: thanks, one more question please. is it possible to print a custom message between two `click.option()`?

Comment: You can always change `click.prompt('username')` to display whatever you want, or add more `print` statements before it.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean that. can you please see the updated question?

Comment: @Yahya If you have a new question then you must create a new post as indicated by the SO rules.

Comment: This is the link for the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59738600/11243953