# how to print a custom message between two @click.option()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm writing a command-line tool using Python [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) package.

I want to print a custom message between two `@click.option()`.

Here is the sample code for what I want to achieve:

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--first', prompt='enter first input')
print('custom message') # want to print custom message here
@click.option('--second', prompt='enter second input')
def add_user(first, second):
    print(first)
    print(second)


add_user()
```

Any help how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback on the first argument:

```
import click

def print_message(ctx, param, args):
    print("Hi")
    return args

@click.command()
@click.option('--first', prompt='enter first input', callback=print_message)
@click.option('--second', prompt='enter second input')
def add_user(first, second):
    print(first)
    print(second)


add_user()

$ python3.8 user.py 
enter first input: one
Hi
enter second input: two
one
two
```