# Click: how to make Argument mutex

Tags: python, click, mutex

I'm writing a CLI using the beautiful [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) library

the use case i want to implement is something like this:

```
cmd <arg> <option --list>

arg: required
--list: optional
```

##### rationale

But... the `--list` show only the available arg
so my purpose is to make all arguments optional in this use case.

I'm started from [this](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/257) request on the official repo, and a [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247099/click-command-line-interfaces-make-options-required-if-other-optional-option-is) very similar but it works only on Options.

I've not found an elegant solution because Arguments works differently,
In my real case I have a lot of arguments and options, so is not possible to reduce all Arguments into Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the click point of view, this is the wrong way to tackle these kind of problem.
The right way is to works with the options priority as described [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/options/#callbacks-and-eager-options)

in this manner the --list options will be treated as the --version.